# pd.merge is not working as usual

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

all,

I have two dataframes: allHoldings and Longswap

allHoldings

```
   prime_broker_id    country_name position_type
0         CS         UNITED STATES          LONG
1         ML         UNITED STATES          LONG
2         CS               AUSTRIA         SHORT
3         HSBC              FRANCE          LONG
4         CITI       UNITED STATES         SHORT
11        DB         UNITED STATES         SHORT
12        JPM        UNITED STATES         SHORT
13        CS                 ITALY         SHORT
14        CITI              TAIWAN         SHORT
15        CITI      UNITED KINGDOM          LONG
16        DB                FRANCE          LONG
17        ML           SOUTH KOREA          LONG
18        CS               AUSTRIA         SHORT
19        CS                 JAPAN          LONG
26        HSBC              FRANCE         SHORT
```

and Longswap

```
   prime_broker_id          country_name  longSpread
0                ML             AUSTRALIA        30.0
1                ML               AUSTRIA        30.0
2                ML               BELGIUM        30.0
3                ML                BRAZIL        50.0
4                ML                CANADA        20.0
5                ML                 CHILE        50.0
6                ML             CHINA - A        75.0
7                ML        CZECH REPUBLIC        45.0
8                ML               DENMARK        30.0
9                ML                 EGYPT        45.0
10               ML               FINLAND        30.0
11               ML                FRANCE        30.0
12               ML               GERMANY        30.0
13               ML             HONG KONG        30.0
14               ML               HUNGARY        45.0
15               ML                 INDIA        75.0
16               ML             INDONESIA        75.0
17               ML               IRELAND        30.0
18               ML                ISRAEL        45.0
19               ML                 ITALY        30.0
20               ML                 JAPAN        30.0
21               ML           SOUTH KOREA        50.0
22               ML            LUXEMBOURG        30.0
23               ML              MALAYSIA        75.0
24               ML                MEXICO        50.0
25               ML           NETHERLANDS        30.0
26               ML           NEW ZEALAND        30.0
27               ML                NORWAY        30.0
28               ML           PHILIPPINES        75.0
```

I have left joined many dataframes before but i am still puzzled as to why it is not working for this example.

Here is my code:

```
allHoldings=pd.merge(allHoldings, Longswap, how='left', left_on = ['prime_broker_id','country_name'], right_on=['prime_broker_id','country_name'])
```

my results are

```
  prime_broker_id    country_name position_type  longSpread
0        CS         UNITED STATES          LONG         NaN
1        ML         UNITED STATES          LONG         NaN
2        CS               AUSTRIA         SHORT         NaN
3        HSBC              FRANCE          LONG         NaN
4        CITI       UNITED STATES         SHORT         NaN
5        DB         UNITED STATES         SHORT         NaN
6        JPM        UNITED STATES         SHORT         NaN
7        CS                 ITALY         SHORT         NaN
```

as you can see the longSpread column is a NaN which does not make any sense. From the longSwap dataframe, this column should be populated.

I am not sure why the left join is not working here.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: No answer so far?

Comment: When I use your data snippet, I get exactly one value of longSpread being populated, namely ML / SOUTH KOREA, which makes sense because it's the only one for which we have data in both tables.  If I go in and change ML to CS for Austria in allHoldings, it works as I'd expect.  Could you find a minimal version of your data which doesn't do what you think it should?

Comment: Let's look at the first records.  In your allHoldings dataframe you have a record containing 'CS' and 'United States', however in Longswap there is no 'CS' record at all. hence 'left' join rules that NaN is populated for longSpread.  This appears to be working as expected.

Comment: @Scott  this is just a snapshot of the data and longSpread column should be populated

Comment: @DSM can you please clarify your question? the merge does not work for all my data so as far as I am concerned the pd.merge does not do what it is supposed to do for the whole dataset...could it be a datatype issue?  when I do dtype it should both as object so in theory that is fine

Comment: @SBad.  Give an example of data where the issue is happening.  It is difficult for us to analyze your problem without being given data and code to replicate the issue.

Comment: @SBad another common problem with merging other that dtypes is whitespace, maybe some of your values on records have a trailing blank or leading blank or more than one blank inbetween words, therefore causing the join to fail.

Comment: @Scott you are right... i think the problem is coming from the whitespace when I do `allHoldings['prime_broker_id'].unique()`  i get  `array(['CS      ', 'ML      ', 'HSBC    ', 'CITI    ', 'DB      ',
       'JPM     ', 'WFPBS   '], dtype=object)`   and  `Longswap['prime_broker_id'].unique()`  i get  `array(['ML', 'BARCAP', 'CITI', 'CS', 'DB', 'GS', 'HSBC', 'JPM', 'MS', 'UBS'], dtype=object)`

Comment: there is a white space thats why it is not merging. somehow i need to remove that. any advice would be most welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer to delete the whitespace and make left join successful

```
allHoldings.prime_broker_id.str.strip()

array(['CS', 'ML', 'HSBC', 'CITI', 'DB', 'JPM', 'WFPBS'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Awesome.  I am glad you found the issue.  Happy coding!